# Select2: No muestra resultados, pero si busca

Tags: java, jquery, select2

los ultimos dias estoy intentando este tema intento utilizar el **select2** me hace la busqueda pero no muestra los resultados, aparte junto al **select2** tengo 2 inputs que se autompletan con la informacion que trae el **ajax**, espero entocntrar solucion a este problema.

**Gracias.**

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-4">Producto</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <select class="form-control select2" id="producto" 
                   style="width: 100%">
                  </select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                 </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $("#producto").select2({
        placeholder: "Buscar producto",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + 'Venta/obtener_producto',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el formato del json que devuelve?? data contiene un objeto? por ejemplo data.items

Comment: Edite la pregunta e puesto una imagen donde respodne tu duda :c

Comment: El results: data tenes que modificar por   results: data.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías cambiar el processResults de la siguiente manera:

```
processResults: function(data) {
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            return {
                id: obj.id,
                text: obj.name
            };
        })
    };
}
```

Generando un nuevo array con dos propiedades (id,text) que es lo que espera select2.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, funciono en una

Comment: Un consulta como hago para que cuando seleciono un resultado se me autorrellene el campo precio y cantidad?